# Css and @mediascreen

Tags: css

I'm having problems with @mediascreen and css. The iPhone and iPad @media only screen CSS will not work together. Only one of them will work depending on which I put first in the stylesheet.

In other words, if I put this first: iPhone [portrait + landscape] */ (+css), it will work on the iPhone, but the /* iPad [portrait + landscape] */ does not work on the iPad.

Here is the CSS:

```css
.abcol {
-webkit-column-count: 5 !important;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px !important;
-webkit-column-rule: 0px dotted black !important;
-moz-column-count: 5 !important;
-moz-column-gap: 10px !important; 
-moz-column-rule: 0px dotted black !important;
column-count: 5 !important;
column-gap: 10px !important;
column-rule: 0px dotted black !important;
 }

/* iPhone [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .abcol {
-webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px; !important;
-webkit-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
-moz-column-count: 2 !important;
-moz-column-gap: 10px; !important;
-moz-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
column-count: 2 !important;
column-gap: 10px; !important;
column-rule: 0px dotted black;
}
  
/* iPad [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .abcol {
-webkit-column-count: 4 !important;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px !important;
-webkit-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
-moz-column-count: 4 !important;
-moz-column-gap: 10px !important; 
-moz-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
column-count: 4 !important;
column-gap: 10px !important;
column-rule: 0px dotted black;
```

Comment: just making sure, do you have the `viewport` meta tag in your HTML `<head>`?

Comment: I'm seeing some syntax errors, you need to close media queries after you open them. `@media screen (...) { ... }`

Comment: OK.. WTH is up with all these `!important` rules?????

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a syntax error, you were missing the closing bracket on your @media screen

```
    /* iPhone [portrait + landscape] */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .abcol {
    -webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px; !important;
    -webkit-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
    -moz-column-count: 2 !important;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px; !important;
    -moz-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
    column-count: 2 !important;
    column-gap: 10px; !important;
    column-rule: 0px dotted black;
      }
    } // this was missing
    /* iPad [portrait + landscape] */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
          .abcol {
    -webkit-column-count: 4 !important;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px !important;
    -webkit-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
    -moz-column-count: 4 !important;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px !important; 
    -moz-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
    column-count: 4 !important;
    column-gap: 10px !important;
    column-rule: 0px dotted black;
      } // added this
    } // & this since they were missing in your included code.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aziz. I really appreciate it.

Comment: just making sure, do you have the viewport meta tag in your HTML <head>?
Yes

I copied your code, but it still does not work. The css works for iPhone, but not for the Ipad where I can still see 5 columns and not 4. Is there anything else I can have overlooked? The website address is: www.bilutleie24.no/wp/ if that helps

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that you have a gap between the different styles?

The iPhone only goes up to 480px and the iPad only goes down to 768px? That is a 288px gap in your media queries, where the styling isn't ipad or iphone.

Comment: Havard, did that work? If not, could you put the code in a plunker?